# Select an option from dynamically produced drop down list

Tags: jquery, html

I am retreiving information on a product from my database and populating a form in order for the user to update the product details.

What I want to do is have the database saved option pre-selected in the dropdown for the user to clearly see what is already loaded for this product.

I am not sure how to do it? I know how to populate a form, I have done so with the text fields, but am not sure how/if it can be down with select lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a default selection on a freshly loaded `SELECT` box, simply set the desired `option` to `selected`'

```
<select id="my-select">
    <option> -- Select -- </option>
    <option value="1">Item One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Item Two</option>
    <option value="3">Item Three</option>
</select>
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$( '#my-select' ).val( 2 );
```

Comment: I am using a php loop to loop through all the values to produce the dropdown list. Can I select this somehow in my loop, not using jquery?

Sorry, may be a pretty dumb question. I've never had to do this before so its confusing me!

Comment: Yes you can. You'll just need to include an `if` statement that outputs the `selected` attribute to the particular `option` you want selected by default.

Answer (score 3):

Go by the value, something like:

```
$('selector').val('whatever')
```

Or if you want, it can be done with the `selected` attribute (in case the value you're  getting from the database is actually on some option's `value` attribute ):

```
$('selector').children('option[value=whatever]').attr('selected','selected')
```

Should select the option you want...